# How to reset MXChip Azure IoT DevKit to stop the Programming LED flashing

Tags: iot-devkit, mxchip

I connected my new MXChip IOT Devkit to my desktop computer and followed the [Get Started guide](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/get-started/#step-5-prepare-development-environment) and had it talking to an Azure IOT Hub with no issues.

I then tried to connect it to a different laptop on a different Wifi (I no longer have access to the other computer or wifi).

I plug in the USB cable and reset the device by holding down the B button and Reset. I then connected to the Wifi successfully (the wifi LED is on).

However, according to the Get started docs it should show the Wifi name but instead, mine shows "IoT DevKit  10.0.0.3  Running....  > Iot Hub". I cannot seem to get it to display the current firmware version.

[image]
[image]

The "Programming" LED never stops flashing and pushing B does NOT cycle through the sensors. Note, in the image above there are 3 LEDs on. Only the Programming LED is constantly flashing.

I deleted all the devices that were registered in the Azure IOT Hub.

I would like to hard reset the device to factory settings and start again but there seems to be no manual or docs for this.

Possibly unrelated, but my Windows 10 laptop does not recognise the device on any USB port (hence I cannot update the firmware). I have installed the st.com Windows USB drivers but result did not change (rebooted).

Another possibly unrelated issues: I cannot install the MMChip Board in Visual Code - it shows the message "Selected Board is not available" even though it says "Done"

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well that was fairly painful and silly. I tried a few more USB cables and on the 3rd cable the "Programming" LED stopped flashing and the device was recognised by Windows. I was then able to upgrade the Firmware to the latest (1.4.1.65 at time of writing) and after the reboot everything is working correctly.

I can confirm that after this the MXChip Board installation was successful too.

Hopefully this helps someone else- the documentation for when things go wrong is lacking!

Comment: I didn’t realize the “Programming” LED needed to be solid in order to show that the device had a good data connection to my computer. Thanks for sharing! I thought my cable was good, but after trying several I found that most of my cables were only able to supply power to the board. I have one cable that works now out of several.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I figured out there is no way of hard-resetting the DevKit hardware through the buttons. However you can always reset the WiFi connection (button B + Reset) (working stable with latest firmware) or enter the configuration mode (A + Reset)- see https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/use-configuration-mode/. If you need to reset the firmware of the board (delete any custom code and show the default IoT DevKit screen with current firmware version) you need to (re-)apply the latest firmware through the firmware upgrading process (https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/firmware-upgrading/). However that assumes a working USB connection otherwise you are kind of lost...